Using e_capture("datazoom") from the echarts4r package bugs out shiny apps that are published on a server?
I have a shiny app where I am trying to capture and use the start/end values of the slider in an echarts4r object. It works perfectly fine when I run my app locally, but when I push it to a Posit Connect server it breaks completely.
The log on the server doesn't show any error or warning messages, but as soon as I move the slider the app no longer responds and it constantly flickers 'Attempting to reconnect...' on the screen. See screenshot below.
Has anybody else come across this issue when they publish their shiny app to a server, and if so, is there a fix?

I tried using other event captures, e.g. e_capture("legendselectchanged"), and these didn't result in issues when the app was on a server. So it appears to be isolated to capturing datazoom.
A minimal reproducible example is below (noting that this code works when run locally, and only results in disconnection issues when published to a Posit Connect server):
library(shiny)
library(echarts4r)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(echarts4rOutput("chart"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$chart <- renderEcharts4r({
    cars |>
      e_charts(speed) |>
      e_scatter(dist) |>
      e_datazoom() |>
      e_capture("datazoom")
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)

